# AWS s3 console shows unexpected error and buckets are not visible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have free tier account(for about 5 months) for learning purpose and I cant see the s3 buckets. the page shows unexpected error. I have tried signout and sign in again but still, the same error is shown and also if I try to create a new bucket i cant create new bucket too, create button is disabled for me.i have pending bill of 50rs is this because of that? some one please help!!

[image]

Comment: Check your browser console & network logs. Paste them here if helpful.

Comment: Go to one of your buckets using an ordinary web browser and a URL in this format: `http://your-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com`.  If you see `<Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code>` then yes, you likely have a problem related to the outstanding bill.  Please advise what you find.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I too have a free account with around 6 months left in it. I was able to access S3 bucket perfectly one day and was unable to do it later and got the same message as you. I looked at AWS forums and installed [S3 browser](http://s3browser.com/) and couldn't find any files with special characters.

When I looked at the console (in Chrome) it had lots of cross-origin request related errors; I found that I had installed a chrome extension **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *** (Description: Allows to you request any site with ajax from any source. Adds to response 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header ). I just disabled this and the s3 buckets loaded perfectly from my chrome web browser.

To re-create the issue, I enabled this chrome extension again but no error came and the S3 buckets loaded normally.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue. Please try to deactivate CORS plugin (chrome) from your browser.